# How to determine if it's my text or others, then appending correctly to listview

Tags: java, android, listview

so far I have the following code:

```
if (c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("type")).toString().contains("1")) {
    Context context = getApplicationContext();
    CharSequence text = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("type")).toString();
    int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
    toast.show();
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.incomming, R.id.message, sms_body);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
} else {
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.outgoing, R.id.message, sms_body);
     lv.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

That works for the most part but it only chooses one, so my question is how to append correctly using the incoming layout or the sending layout, this is my first time getting this "fancy" with listviews so **ANY** help is really appreciated! Thanks.

QUESTION:
   What I mean is I want it to look like the iOS messenger or better yet the Facebook messenger, like if its a inbox message it's blue, if it's mine its gray layout.

EXTRA INFO:
    It gets the messages of all of the inbox and sent box to the number that just text you. Any other info you need lemme know!

FULL CODE: http://pastebin.com/NmV39ajq

Fusion.

Comment: your question is not clear

Comment: What I mean is I want it to look like the iOS messenger or better yet the Facebook messenger, like if its a inbox message it's blue, if it's mine its gray layout.,

Comment: then set `message` textview color in both xml's blue and gray

Comment: It doesn't work like that. sms_body is an array and it keeps making all of them one color or the other.

Comment: but your are using  two layouts `incomming` and `outgoing` then you can set color for both messages

Comment: The layouts are blue or gray but as I said what it is doing is making all gray or all blue.

Comment: if `sms_boby` is an Array then how you are going to differentiate between inbox and mine messags?

Comment: Updated with more in-depth code. Also here: http://pastebin.com/NmV39ajq

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently you are changing ListView layout which is not right way to show more then one layout for ListView row:

**1.** Create a custom adapter which use two layouts for rows one for inbox another for mine messages.

See following example:
[Multiple Layout ListView](http://android.leocardz.com/multiple-layout-listview/)

**2.** Use ArrayList with custom class object as data-source  which contain message type and message body

```
public class MessageDetails{
 private String mesgType;
 private String mesgBody;
 // create getter/setter methods to set/get both variables values

}
```

**3.** Create a ArrayList with `MessageDetails` class objects:

```
ArrayList<MessageDetails>  arrMessageDetails=new ArrayList<MessageDetails>;
if (c.moveToLast()) {
 do {
       if (c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("address")) == null) {
            c.moveToNext();
            continue;
        }

 String Body = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("body"))
                            .toString();
 CharSequence text = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("type")).toString();
 MessageDetails object=new MessageDetails();
 object.setmesgType(text);
 object.setmesgBody(Body);
 arrMessageDetails.add(object);
} while (c.moveToPrevious());
```

**4.** Use `arrMessageDetails` as data source to Adapter :

```
CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(this,R.id.message, arrMessageDetails);
lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```